# Cannot detect and install the selected platform. The java or javac may not be executable

Tags: java, netbeans

I have recently installed netbeans 11. And open an existing maven project which is run properly on netbeans 8.2.That project runs on jdk1.7.In netbeans select manage platforms and I want to add jdk 1.7, there is error like that

> Cannot detect and install the selected platform. The java or javac may not be executable.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-nb-javac-in). You may have to install/activate the nb-javac plugin, which is no longer pre-installed in NB<11.

Comment: Thank you GameDroids I have checked nb-javac plugin.It installed on nb11.But the situation is go on

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue , was not able to add jdk 8 on netbeans 12.2.
In windows normally user do not have write access on "Program Files" folder , make sure if your netbeans is installed in Program Files directory run it as Adminstrator and then try to add new platform it will work.